# Am I supposed to manually call move on non-reference constructor parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Given this constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass(SomeOtherClass other)
    : myOther(other)
{
}
```

Should I be manually calling `std::move` in the initializer list, or will the compiler be smart enough to do it automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You* have to call it. The compiler can't know whether you still want to "use" the object later (and in any case that would be a very confusing language rule). So say `: myOther(std::move(other))`.

Comment: In theory, the language spec could say that if the compiler can prove that a given variable was only used by destruction after a certain point, that its use can be implicitly turned into a `move`, then the above case could be simple enough for a compiler to do that proof.  But such a proof would be both exceedingly fragile (the compiler would have to analyze the move/copy constructor of `myOther` to ensure that it doesn't do anything strange with global state), and would break far more code than existing auto-`move`.  That language spec does *not* say this, other than maybe the `as-if` rule.